Why does my sample code not receive an ACK from a SYN?
What I am trying to do it verify a device under test behavior for RFC5961. To verify, it's necessary in inject a RST packet with a sequence number in the window, but not the expect number. So I am using a Linux Ubuntu 18 machine to create packets.
The first step is to establish a connection.  And that is not working.  The example I found closes the socket, and the code I try to rewrite never gets a ACK from the DUT.  Once I get past that, it should be easy.
Initially, I used these examples  https://pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html
which shows how to create a raw (TCP) packet to send a SYN and get an ACK.
Packet 1 and 2 and perfect.  But packet 3 isn't generated by the code.
The problem is that after the ACK to the SYN, Linux is sending a RST on it's own. I learned that is because the socket has nothing listening or connected.  I don't know how to get around that, since it's closing before my test even has a chance to issue a "revcfrom()"

When I tried to make any modifications to the code to customize it, the DUT doesn't even reply with an ACK.  Despite the packets being essentially identical.
I consulted these, however they did not provide an answer.
Sending Raw ethernet packet containing IPv4 and TCP SYN but not getting SYN/ACK packet in response packet
STARTED getting RST packet from client socket after I replied SYN packet with SYN + ACK packet
A few years ago, I created a 802.1x Wired modification, creating Ethernet packets of type 0x888e.  It all worked by going "full raw" with the packet, and building it from scratch.  So I thought "why not just create the packet myself?"
Still, the DUT doesn't reply with an ACK, or anything else.
My setup is my Linux Ubuntu 18 and the DUT on the same NetGear "Prosafe JGS524E".  They were assigned IP addresses by an ATT router.  Historically, I have been able to fabricate raw packets and send them to the DUT.
The both tests of the entire code, which is only to hit a DUT, has hardcoded values. Two examples are shown here.  And WireShark screen shots showing the packets are included.
The question:  Why is the packet from the second code not getting a response?
The entire Buchan code which sends the SYN and gets the ACK, then Linux sends the RST is here:
{   Code exceeded the limit of an allowed post...  see Buchan's example here: 

https://pdbuchan.com/rawsock/tcp4.c }
Here is my code (build from a RAW ethernet code that creates 802.1X packets, and works for 802.1X).  When I fabricate a packet that is virtually identical to the code above, the DUT doesn't even respond.  I have tried so many variations, it's not worth all the extra bandwidth to post those.  None work.
Wireshark analysis doesn't show any issues with the packet.  Just the one lone packet to the same MAC/IP which the DUT doesn't respond.

The code is broken into "main" and a "packet" class.  Much of it taken from the above example
Main.cpp:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>       // struct ip and IP_MAXPACKET (which is 65535)
#include <netinet/in.h>       // IPPROTO_RAW, IPPROTO_IP, IPPROTO_TCP, INET_ADDRSTRLEN
#define __FAVOR_BSD           // Use BSD format of tcp header
#include <netinet/tcp.h>      // struct tcphdr
#include <arpa/inet.h>        // inet_pton() and inet_ntop()

#include <errno.h>
#include "Packet.h"

int BuildEthernetHdr(unsigned char *buffer, uint8_t *src_ip, uint8_t *dst_ip);
int BuildIPHdr(unsigned char *buffer, const char *src_ip, const char *dst_ip);
int BuildTCPHdr(unsigned char *buffer);

uint16_t checksum (uint8_t *addr, int len);

unsigned char buffer[2048];
int main() {
    int len;
    unsigned char *pkt;
    CPacket packet;

    uint8_t     srcMac[6];
    uint8_t     dstMac[6];

    memcpy(srcMac, "\x60\xa4\x4c\x63\x4d\x9e", 6);
    memcpy(dstMac, "\xa4\x9b\x13\x00\xfe\x0e", 6);

    packet.SetInterface("SetInterface");
    packet.Initialize();
    pkt = buffer;
    len = BuildEthernetHdr(pkt,srcMac, dstMac);
    pkt += len;

    len = BuildIPHdr(pkt, "192.168.1.211","192.168.1.94");
    pkt += len;

    len = BuildTCPHdr(pkt);
    pkt += len;

    puts("---  IP HEADER ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < pkt - buffer; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
        if ((i& 0x0f) == 0x0f) puts("");
    }
    puts("");
    len = pkt - buffer;

    packet.SendMessage(buffer, len);

    packet.Cleanup();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#define IP4_HDRLEN      20
#define TCP_HDRLEN      20
#define ETH_HDRLEN      14

int BuildEthernetHdr(unsigned char *buffer, uint8_t *src_mac, uint8_t *dst_mac) {
    ETHERHDR * ethhdr;
    ethhdr = (ETHERHDR * )buffer;

    memcpy(ethhdr->srcMac, src_mac,6);
    memcpy(ethhdr->dstMac, dst_mac,6);
    ethhdr->etherType = htons(0x0800);

    return sizeof(ETHERHDR);
}

int BuildIPHdr(unsigned char *buffer, const char *src_ip, const char *dst_ip) {
    struct ip *iphdr;
    int status;
    unsigned int ip_flags[4];
    iphdr = (struct ip*) buffer;

    iphdr->ip_hl = IP4_HDRLEN / sizeof (uint32_t);

    // Internet Protocol version (4 bits): IPv4
    iphdr->ip_v = 4;

    // Type of service (8 bits)
    iphdr->ip_tos = 0;

    // Total length of datagram (16 bits): IP header + TCP header
    iphdr->ip_len = htons (IP4_HDRLEN + TCP_HDRLEN);

    // ID sequence number (16 bits): unused, since single datagram
    iphdr->ip_id = htons (0);

    // Flags, and Fragmentation offset (3, 13 bits): 0 since single datagram

    // Zero (1 bit)
    ip_flags[0] = 0;

    // Do not fragment flag (1 bit)
    ip_flags[1] = 1;

    // More fragments following flag (1 bit)
    ip_flags[2] = 0;

    // Fragmentation offset (13 bits)
    ip_flags[3] = 0;

    iphdr->ip_off = htons ((ip_flags[0] << 15)
                          + (ip_flags[1] << 14)
                          + (ip_flags[2] << 13)
                          +  ip_flags[3]);

    // Time-to-Live (8 bits): default to maximum value
    iphdr->ip_ttl = 64;

    // Transport layer protocol (8 bits): 6 for TCP
    iphdr->ip_p = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Source IPv4 address (32 bits)
    if ((status = inet_pton (AF_INET, src_ip, &(iphdr->ip_src))) != 1) {
      fprintf (stderr, "inet_pton() failed for source address.\nError message: %s", strerror (status));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      // Destination IPv4 address (32 bits)
      if ((status = inet_pton (AF_INET, dst_ip, &(iphdr->ip_dst))) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "inet_pton() failed for destination address.\nError message: %s", strerror (status));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      // IPv4 header checksum (16 bits): set to 0 when calculating checksum
      iphdr->ip_sum = 0;
      iphdr->ip_sum = checksum (buffer, IP4_HDRLEN);

      return sizeof(struct ip);
}

int BuildTCPHdr(unsigned char *buffer) {

    struct tcphdr *tcphdr;
    int optsize = 0;
    unsigned int tcp_flags[8];
    unsigned char optbuffer[20];

    tcphdr = (struct tcphdr *) buffer;
    if (false) {
      //  Option     length (with itself)          value
        optbuffer[0] = 2; optbuffer[1] = 4; optbuffer[2] = 5; optbuffer [3] = 0xb4;   //Max Seg Size
        optbuffer[4] = 4; optbuffer[5] = 2;      // SACK permitted
      uint32_t time1 = 0x12345678;  uint32_t time2 = 0x87654321;
      optbuffer[6] = 8; optbuffer[7] = 10;  memcpy(&optbuffer[8], &time1, 4); memcpy(&optbuffer[12], &time2, 4);
      optbuffer[16] = 1; // NoOp
      optbuffer[17] = 3; optbuffer[18] = 3; optbuffer[19] = 7;     // Shift Multiplier
      optsize = 20;
    }
  // Source port number (16 bits)
  tcphdr->th_sport = htons (8080);

  // Destination port number (16 bits)
  tcphdr->th_dport = htons (80);

  // Sequence number (32 bits)
  tcphdr->th_seq = htonl (5);

  // Acknowledgement number (32 bits): 0 in first packet of SYN/ACK process
  tcphdr->th_ack = htonl (0);

  // Reserved (4 bits): should be 0
  tcphdr->th_x2 = 0;

  // Data offset (4 bits): size of TCP header in 32-bit words
  tcphdr->th_off = (TCP_HDRLEN + optsize) / 4;

  // Flags (8 bits)

  // FIN flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[0] = 0;

  // SYN flag (1 bit): set to 1
  tcp_flags[1] = 1;

  // RST flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[2] = 0;

  // PSH flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[3] = 0;

  // ACK flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[4] = 0;

  // URG flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[5] = 0;

  // ECE flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[6] = 0;

  // CWR flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[7] = 0;

  tcphdr->th_flags = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    tcphdr->th_flags += (tcp_flags[i] << i);
  }

  // Window size (16 bits)
  tcphdr->th_win = htons (8192);

  // Urgent pointer (16 bits): 0 (only valid if URG flag is set)
  tcphdr->th_urp = htons (0);

  // TCP checksum (16 bits)
  tcphdr->th_sum = checksum (buffer, sizeof(struct tcphdr));

    return sizeof(struct tcphdr);

}



// Computing the internet checksum (RFC 1071).
// Note that the internet checksum is not guaranteed to preclude collisions.
uint16_t checksum (uint8_t *addr, int len) {

  int count = len;
  register uint32_t sum = 0;
  uint16_t answer = 0;

  // Sum up 2-byte values until none or only one byte left.
  while (count > 0) {
    sum += *(addr++);
    count -= 1;
  }


  // Fold 32-bit sum into 16 bits; we lose information by doing this,
  // increasing the chances of a collision.
  // sum = (lower 16 bits) + (upper 16 bits shifted right 16 bits)
  while (sum >> 16) {
    sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);
  }

  // Checksum is one's compliment of sum.
  answer = ~sum;

  return (answer);
}

Packet.cpp (most of my C++ programming is to wrap C code for encapsulation, to to make it difficult to a C developer)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>       // struct ip and IP_MAXPACKET (which is 65535)
#define __FAVOR_BSD           // Use BSD format of tcp header
#include <netinet/tcp.h>      // struct tcphdr

//#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
//#include <arpa/inet.h>

//#include <netinet/ip.h>
//#include <netinet/udp.h>
//#include <netinet/ether.h>

//#include <sys/select.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include "Packet.h"
  //   Source (me) is 60:a4:4c:63:4d:9e
  //   DUT is     a4:9b:13:00:fe:0e
CPacket::CPacket() {
    m_socket = -1;


}
CPacket::~CPacket() {
    Cleanup();
}

void CPacket::Cleanup() {

}

void CPacket::SetInterface(const char * iface) {
    strcpy(m_interface, iface);
}

bool CPacket::Initialize() {
    int result;
    Cleanup();
    // open a socket
    m_socket = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);

    if (m_socket == -1) {
        result = errno;
        puts("Failed to create raw socket");
        puts(strerror(result));
        return false;
    }
    // Get the interface
    memset(&m_if_idx,0,sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strcpy(m_if_idx.ifr_name,"enp3s0");
    result = ioctl(m_socket, SIOCGIFINDEX,  &m_if_idx);
    if (result == -1) {
        result = errno;
        puts("Failed to get IF info");
        puts(strerror(result));
        return false;
    }

    memset(&m_if_mac,0,sizeof(struct ifreq));

    strcpy((char *) m_if_mac.ifr_name,"enp3s0");
    result = ioctl(m_socket, SIOCGIFHWADDR,  &m_if_mac);
    if (result == -1) {
        result = errno;
        puts("Failed to get MAC info");
        puts(strerror(result));
        return false;
    }

    m_socket_address.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    m_socket_address.sll_ifindex = m_if_idx.ifr_ifindex;
    m_socket_address.sll_protocol = htons(0x0008);

    result = bind(m_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&m_socket_address,sizeof(m_socket_address));
    if (result == -1) {
        result = errno;
        puts("Failed to BIND");
        puts(strerror(result));
        return false;
    }

    //  Configure the socket address struct we will use to send
    memset(&m_socket_address,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    //  The MAc appears to be ignored.  So can be left as all nulls
    m_socket_address.sll_ifindex = m_if_idx.ifr_ifru.ifru_ivalue;
    m_socket_address.sll_halen = 6;

    return true;
}

bool CPacket::SendMessage(unsigned char *msg, uint16_t len) {
    int result;

#ifdef PACKET_DUMP
    puts("---- PACKET DUMP TX----");
    for (int x = 0; x < len; x++) {
        printf("%02x ", m_buffer[x]);
        if ((x & 0x0f) == 0x0f) puts("");
    }
    puts("\n------------");
#endif
    //  And fire away
    result = sendto(m_socket, msg,len,0, (struct sockaddr*) &m_socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    if (result != len) {
        result = errno;
        puts("Failed to send");
        puts(strerror(result));
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}



uint8_t CPacket::ReceiveMessage(uint32_t delay, unsigned char *msg) {
    int result;
    unsigned int size;
    uint32_t usec, sec;
    ETHERHDR * etherhdr;
    etherhdr = (ETHERHDR *) msg;
    fd_set rxset;
    struct timeval timeout;

    delay *= 1000;      // Milli to micro...

    sec = delay / 1000000;
    usec = delay % 1000000;
    //printf ("  delay for %d sec, %d usec\n", sec, usec);

    timeout.tv_sec = sec;
    timeout.tv_usec = usec;

    FD_ZERO(&rxset);
    FD_SET(m_socket,&rxset);

    result = select(m_socket + 1,&rxset,NULL,NULL,&timeout);
    if (result == 0 ) {
        puts("Recv timeout");
        return 0;
    }

    size = sizeof(m_socket_address);
    do {
        //  And read away
        result = recvfrom(m_socket, msg,1100,0, (struct sockaddr*) &m_socket_address, &size);
        if (result == -1) {
            result = errno;
            puts("Failed to receive...");
            puts(strerror(result));
            return 0;
        }
#ifdef PACKET_DUMP
        printf("---- PACKET DUMP RX---- %d bytes\n", result);
        for (int x = 0; x < result; x++) {
            printf("%02x ", m_buffer[x]);
            if ((x & 0x0f) == 0x0f) puts("");
        }
        puts("\n------------");
#endif
        if (memcmp(etherhdr->srcMac,m_if_mac.ifr_ifru.ifru_hwaddr.sa_data,6) == 0) {
            //puts(" Packet from me...");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } while (1);

    return (uint8_t ) result;
}

And the header to the class Packet.h
/*
 * Comm.h
 *
 *  Created on: Apr 21, 2022
 *      Author: scott
 */
#pragma once
//  Headers neded that defined the IF structs
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <net/if.h>


typedef struct etherhdr {
    uint8_t     dstMac[6];
    uint8_t     srcMac[6];
    uint16_t    etherType;      //0x0008
} ETHERHDR;

class CPacket {
public:
    CPacket();
    ~CPacket();
    void SetInterface(const char * iface);
    bool Initialize();

    bool SendMessage(unsigned char * msg, uint16_t len);
    uint8_t ReceiveMessage(uint32_t delay, unsigned char *msg);
    void Cleanup();

private:

    int         m_socket;
    char        m_interface[32];

    struct ifreq m_if_idx;
    struct ifreq m_if_mac;

    struct sockaddr_ll m_socket_address;

};

I also decided to sniff some other stuff.  I sniffed a packet from a browser, and saw TCP options present, so I build the packet to optionally support that (evident in the code, although disabled in the version I pasted)
Here is a browser request.  It has nothing surprising that anyone with lower level Ethernet wouldn't know):

Here is a request where I added option, but it still did not get an ACK from the DUT.

Once I get past this issue, I can fabricate a data packet, the inject a RST packet to test my implementation of the RFC5961 compliance in the DUT.
Side note:  The DUT uses a small window, and short lived sockets, so the issue is moot in that the DUT isn't really vulnerable to the DOS attack.  But try to convince a customer of that when they spent an exorbitant amount of money on test app, and it just erroneously reports that this is a open attack.

I am able to get the DUT to respond to the fabricated packet.
It appears the checksums were computed badly.  I updated the check sum for the TCP computation, since I learned that the TCP needs to have a "pseudo IP" header to make the computation. It's explained here:
Calculation of TCP Checksum
I also restructured the code to build it from the inside out (TCP-> IP-> Ethernet) and the DUT responds to the SYN.
I also disabled "Checksum offload" on the Linux PC to be sure, and to allow me to see and verify the checksums.
So the result: it puts me back to my first reported challenge trying to fabricate a test for RFC5961:
The problem is that after the ACK to the SYN, Linux is sending a RST on it's own. I learned that is because the socket has nothing listening or connected. I don't know how to get around that, since it's closing before my test even has a chance to issue a "revcfrom()"

For anyone who is interested, here is the updated code for "main.cpp".  It's not meant to be robust or defensive, just to test fabricating a packet from the Ethernet level.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>       // struct ip and IP_MAXPACKET (which is 65535)
#include <netinet/in.h>       // IPPROTO_RAW, IPPROTO_IP, IPPROTO_TCP, INET_ADDRSTRLEN
#define __FAVOR_BSD           // Use BSD format of tcp header
#include <netinet/tcp.h>      // struct tcphdr
#include <arpa/inet.h>        // inet_pton() and inet_ntop()

#include <errno.h>
#include "Packet.h"

int BuildEthernetHdr(unsigned char **buffer, uint8_t *src_ip, uint8_t *dst_ip);
int BuildIPHdr(unsigned char **buffer, const char *src_ip, const char *dst_ip);
int BuildTCPHdr(unsigned char **buffer, const char *, const char *);

uint16_t checksum (uint8_t *addr, int len);

unsigned char buffer[2048];
int main() {
    int tcplen, iplen, maclen, len;
    unsigned char *eth, *tcp, *ip, *pkt;
    CPacket packet;

    uint8_t     srcMac[6];
    uint8_t     dstMac[6];

    tcplen = BuildTCPHdr(&tcp, "192.168.1.211","192.168.1.94");

    iplen = BuildIPHdr(&ip, "192.168.1.211","192.168.1.94");
    //  Know your MAC addresses... 
    memcpy(srcMac, "\x60\xa4\x4c\x63\x4d\x9e", 6);
    memcpy(dstMac, "\xa4\x9b\x13\x00\xfe\x0e", 6);

    maclen = BuildEthernetHdr(&eth,srcMac, dstMac);

    packet.Initialize();

    pkt = buffer;

    memcpy(pkt,eth, maclen);
    pkt += maclen;
    memcpy(pkt,ip, iplen);
    pkt += iplen;
    memcpy(pkt,tcp, tcplen);
    pkt += tcplen;

    len = pkt - buffer;

    packet.SendMessage(buffer, len);
    free(tcp);
    free(ip);
    free(eth);
    packet.Cleanup();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#define IP4_HDRLEN      20
#define TCP_HDRLEN      20
#define ETH_HDRLEN      14

int BuildEthernetHdr(uint8_t **buffer, uint8_t *src_mac, uint8_t *dst_mac) {
    ETHERHDR * ethhdr;
    ethhdr = (ETHERHDR * )malloc(sizeof(ETHERHDR));

    memcpy(ethhdr->srcMac, src_mac,6);
    memcpy(ethhdr->dstMac, dst_mac,6);
    ethhdr->etherType = htons(0x0800);

    *buffer = (uint8_t*) ethhdr;

    return sizeof(ETHERHDR);
}

int BuildIPHdr(uint8_t **buffer, const char *src_ip, const char *dst_ip) {
    struct ip *iphdr;
    int status;
    unsigned int ip_flags[4];
    iphdr = (struct ip*) malloc(sizeof(struct ip));
    memset(iphdr,0,sizeof(struct ip));

    iphdr->ip_hl = IP4_HDRLEN / sizeof (uint32_t);

    // Internet Protocol version (4 bits): IPv4
    iphdr->ip_v = 4;

    // Type of service (8 bits)
    iphdr->ip_tos = 0;

    // Total length of datagram (16 bits): IP header + TCP header
    iphdr->ip_len = htons (IP4_HDRLEN + TCP_HDRLEN);

    // ID sequence number (16 bits): unused, since single datagram
    iphdr->ip_id = htons (0);

    // Flags, and Fragmentation offset (3, 13 bits): 0 since single datagram

    // Zero (1 bit)
    ip_flags[0] = 0;

    // Do not fragment flag (1 bit)
    ip_flags[1] = 1;

    // More fragments following flag (1 bit)
    ip_flags[2] = 0;

    // Fragmentation offset (13 bits)
    ip_flags[3] = 0;

    iphdr->ip_off = htons ((ip_flags[0] << 15)
                          + (ip_flags[1] << 14)
                          + (ip_flags[2] << 13)
                          +  ip_flags[3]);

    // Time-to-Live (8 bits): default to maximum value
    iphdr->ip_ttl = 64;

    // Transport layer protocol (8 bits): 6 for TCP
    iphdr->ip_p = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Source IPv4 address (32 bits)
    if ((status = inet_pton (AF_INET, src_ip, &(iphdr->ip_src))) != 1) {
      fprintf (stderr, "inet_pton() failed for source address.\nError message: %s", strerror (status));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      // Destination IPv4 address (32 bits)
      if ((status = inet_pton (AF_INET, dst_ip, &(iphdr->ip_dst))) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "inet_pton() failed for destination address.\nError message: %s", strerror (status));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      // IPv4 header checksum (16 bits): set to 0 when calculating checksum
      iphdr->ip_sum = 0;
      iphdr->ip_sum = checksum ((uint8_t*) iphdr, IP4_HDRLEN);

      printf("IP Chk %x\n", iphdr->ip_sum);

      *buffer = (uint8_t *)iphdr;
      return sizeof(struct ip);
}


typedef struct {
    uint32_t srcIP[1];
    uint32_t dstIP[1];
    uint8_t res[1];
    uint8_t proto[1];
    uint16_t len[1];
} IP_PSEUDO;

uint8_t * PseudoHeader(uint8_t * packet, uint16_t len, uint32_t dst, uint32_t src) {
    IP_PSEUDO * iphdr;
    memmove(&packet[12], packet, len);
    iphdr = (IP_PSEUDO*)packet;
    iphdr->dstIP[0] = dst;      // 5e = 94
    iphdr->srcIP[0] = src;      // d3 = 211
    iphdr->res[0] = 0;
    iphdr->proto[0] = 6;
    iphdr->len[0] = htons(len);
    return &packet[20];
}

int BuildTCPHdr(uint8_t **buffer, const char * src, const char *dest) {

    struct tcphdr *tcphdr;
    int optsize = 0;
    unsigned int tcp_flags[8];
    unsigned char optbuffer[20];

    tcphdr = (struct tcphdr *) malloc(sizeof(struct tcphdr));
    memset(tcphdr,0,sizeof(struct tcphdr));
    if (false) {
      //  Option     length (with itself)          value
        optbuffer[0] = 2; optbuffer[1] = 4; optbuffer[2] = 5; optbuffer [3] = 0xb4;   //Max Seg Size
        optbuffer[4] = 4; optbuffer[5] = 2;      // SACK permitted
      uint32_t time1 = 0x12345678;  uint32_t time2 = 0x87654321;
      optbuffer[6] = 8; optbuffer[7] = 10;  memcpy(&optbuffer[8], &time1, 4); memcpy(&optbuffer[12], &time2, 4);
      optbuffer[16] = 1; // NoOp
      optbuffer[17] = 3; optbuffer[18] = 3; optbuffer[19] = 7;     // Shift Multiplier
      optsize = 20;
    }
  // Source port number (16 bits)
  tcphdr->th_sport = htons (32500);

  // Destination port number (16 bits)
  tcphdr->th_dport = htons (80);

  // Sequence number (32 bits)
  tcphdr->th_seq = htonl (5);

  // Acknowledgement number (32 bits): 0 in first packet of SYN/ACK process
  tcphdr->th_ack = htonl (0);

  // Reserved (4 bits): should be 0
  tcphdr->th_x2 = 0;

  // Data offset (4 bits): size of TCP header in 32-bit words
  tcphdr->th_off = (TCP_HDRLEN + optsize) / 4;

  // Flags (8 bits)

  // FIN flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[0] = 0;

  // SYN flag (1 bit): set to 1
  tcp_flags[1] = 1;

  // RST flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[2] = 0;

  // PSH flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[3] = 0;

  // ACK flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[4] = 0;

  // URG flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[5] = 0;

  // ECE flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[6] = 0;

  // CWR flag (1 bit)
  tcp_flags[7] = 0;

  tcphdr->th_flags = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    tcphdr->th_flags += (tcp_flags[i] << i);
  }

  // Window size (16 bits)
  tcphdr->th_win = htons (8192);

  // Urgent pointer (16 bits): 0 (only valid if URG flag is set)
  tcphdr->th_urp = htons (0);

  // TCP checksum (16 bits)
  uint8_t temp[64];
  memset(temp,0,64);
  uint32_t ip_src, ip_dest;
  inet_pton (AF_INET, src, &ip_src);
  inet_pton (AF_INET, dest, &ip_dest);
  memcpy(temp,tcphdr,sizeof(struct tcphdr));
  
  PseudoHeader(temp,20, ip_src,ip_dest);

  tcphdr->th_sum = checksum(temp, sizeof(struct tcphdr) + 12);
  printf("TCP Chk %x\n", tcphdr->th_sum);
  
  *buffer = (uint8_t*) tcphdr;
  return sizeof(struct tcphdr);

}


// Computing the internet checksum (RFC 1071).
// Note that the internet checksum is not guaranteed to preclude collisions.
uint16_t checksum(uint8_t *addr, int len) {

    int count = len;
    register uint32_t sum = 0;
    uint16_t answer = 0;

    // Sum up 2-byte values until none or only one byte left.
    while (count > 1) {
        printf(" Adding %04x \n", *((unsigned short *)(addr)));
        sum += htons(*((unsigned short *)(addr)));
        addr += 2;
        count -= 2;
    }

    // Add left-over byte, if any.
    if (count > 0) {
        sum += *(uint8_t *)addr;
    }

    // Fold 32-bit sum into 16 bits; we lose information by doing this,
    // increasing the chances of a collision.
    // sum = (lower 16 bits) + (upper 16 bits shifted right 16 bits)
    sum = htonl(sum);
    while (sum >> 16) {
        sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);
    }

    // Checksum is one's compliment of sum.
    answer = ~sum;

    return (answer);
}

